# Do different birds effect game play?

Tags: dont-touch-the-spikes

You can purchase different birds with the lollies, but do different birds have an effect on game play when selected?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only reason the birds are there are for cosmetic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do. I bought one for 1000 candy things and it moves faster than the default bird.